# Partially fill SVG element by setting a value

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to make an interactive health bar in my SVG dog interface. Idea is very simple: suppose we have 100hp, then the element is fully red, if we have 50hp, the element is half-red. 
Here is the code of the SVG health bar element:

```
 <g id="health">
    <path d="M896.4,1306A640.84,640.84,0,0,1,624.63,531.87H825.44A575.33,575.33,0,0,0,758,644.49a572.13,572.13,0,0,0-4.39,461.89,577.14,577.14,0,0,0,126.64,184.31Q888.18,1298.5,896.4,1306Z" transform="translate(-537.36 -66.14)" /> </g>
```

CSS:

```
#health {
  fill: white;
  height: 20%;
}
```

JS:

```
// Finding element by id
let health = document.getElementById('health');
let hp = 100;

// Controlling the element
health.onclick = function () {
  health.style.fill = 'red';
};
```

For now, all I have is just a color control on click, I want there to be a numeric value that will control CSS fill property, but I don’t know how to do that. I am trying to achieve the following picture: [image: example of changing bars]

The red color is the one I wish to control.

Thank you, 
Liana

**UPDATE:** full version https://github.com/liana-webdev/dog_interface

Comment: Your SVG doesn't render :(

Comment: Sorry, I included only a part of it... I will include the whole SVG file, one sec!

Comment: @GalAbra Done.. I quickly made a repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a linearGradient to do this. We need two gradient stops at the same place to give a sharp colour change.

```js
// Finding element by id
let health = document.getElementById('health');
let c = document.getElementById('g').children;
let hp = 20;

// Controlling the element
health.onclick = function () {
  let pct = hp / 100;
  c[1].offset.baseVal = c[2].offset.baseVal = pct;
};
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-400 300 1800 1800">
 <defs>
   <linearGradient id="g" x2="0" y1="100%" y2="0%">  
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="red"/>
      <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="black"/>  
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="health">
    <path id="health" d="M896.4,1306A640.84,640.84,0,0,1,624.63,531.87H825.44A575.33,575.33,0,0,0,758,644.49a572.13,572.13,0,0,0-4.39,461.89,577.14,577.14,0,0,0,126.64,184.31Q888.18,1298.5,896.4,1306Z" transform="translate(-537.36 -66.14)" fill="url(#g)"/> </g>
</svg>
```